# Show that $\frac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ in probability if $s<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent random variables and  with distributions:
$$P(X_n=n^s)=P(X_n=-n^s)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Let $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$. Show that 
$$\frac{S_n}{n}\to 0 \text{ in probability, if } s<\frac{1}{2}$$

---

My attempt: $\frac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ in probability means that
$$\forall \epsilon>0:\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\mid \frac{S_n}{n}\mid >\epsilon)\to 0$$
So we have to consider $P(\mid \frac{S_n}{n}\mid >\epsilon)$. Now using Chebychev:
$$P(\mid \frac{S_n}{n}\mid >\epsilon)\leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon}E(S_n)$$
So now we want to find a  bound on $E(S_n)$. But (unless I'm overlooking something here), we can easily see that $E(S_n)=0$, independently of $s$ and $n$. Hence  we would conclude that
$$\forall s:P(\mid \frac{S_n}{n}\mid >\epsilon)\leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon}E(S_n)=0$$
Which is of course not true. So I suspect I'm making a mistake with applying Chebychev's inequality, but I do not see what the mistake is.

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality involves the variance, where do you compute that?

Comment: @Nate some authors refer to $P(X> a) \leq \frac{1}{a}E[X]$ as Chebyshev

Comment: You might be mixing up markov's inequality, in which case the rhs of the inequality should have $E|S_n|$ rather than $E(S_n)$, with the special case chebychev's in which case the rhs of the inequality should have $VarS_n$. Either way the rhs is $\neq 0$.

Comment: @snarfblaat thanks, you're right. After some googling it turns out that what my lecture notes refer to as chebychevs inequality is usually called markovs inequality . You're also right that I forgot the absolute value, which solves my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$VarX_n=EX_n^2=n^{2s},VarS_n=\sum_{j=1}^n j^{2s}$ so chebychev's inequality gives $P(|S_n/n|>\epsilon)\le \sum_{j=1}^nj^{2s}/(n^2\epsilon^2)\sim \int_1^nx^{2s}dx/(n^2\epsilon^2) \sim n^{2s+1}/(n^2\epsilon^2)\to 0$ iff $2s-1<0, s<1/2$. I assumed $s\neq-1/2$ for the integral approximation, but that case is analogous.